# OpenLayers 3 - SelectInteraction Event Not Firing

Tags: openlayers-3

I am trying to fire the select event for a selectInteraction. Here is the code I have so far:

```
// create and instance of the selectInteraction
var selectInteraction = new ol.interaction.Select( {
    layers: myLayers
} );

// add select event handler
// NOT BEING CALLED WHEN FEATURES ARE PUSHED TO SELECTED ARRAY
selectInteraction.on( "select", function ( evt ) {

    var selected = evt.selected;
    var deselected = evt.deselected;

    selected.forEach( function( feature ) {
        feature.setStyle( myCustomStyleFunction );
    } );

    deselected.forEach( function( feature ) {
        feature.setStyle( null );
    } );


}, selectInteraction );

// add the interaction to the map
myMap.getInteractions().extend( [ selectInteraction ] );

// function called with feature to be selected
function programmaticallySelectFeature( feature ) {

    // get the selectInteraction for the map
    myMap.getInteractions().forEach( function ( interaction ) {

        if ( interaction instanceof ol.interaction.Select ) {
            selectInteraction =  interaction;
        }

    });

    // push the feature to the selectInteraction
    selectInteraction.getFeatures().push( feature );

}
```

I understand that the select event is not firing when features are pushed to the selected array. Otherwise it works as expected. So how can get this to work? Can I listen for another event perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

you can listen to the events click or singleclick on the map, and push the returned feature in the selected features:

```
map.on('click', function(evt){
    var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer) {
        return feature;
    });
    if(feature){
        selectInteraction.getFeatures().push(feature);
    }
 });
```

this of course assuming you want to select features with a click